# Unable to install RDCOMClient packages in R

Tags: r

I am working a project where i suppose to send mail to outlook through R.
I am not able to install package RDCOMClient which is important to send mail to outlook using R.
Can anyone help me to resolve the issue related to RDCOMClient packages or can suggest alternative package to send mail to outlook using R.
Below are different codes that i have already tried out to resolve RDCOMClient package installation issue. But still not able to figure it out

```
install.packages("RDCOMClient")
devtools::install_github("omegahat/RDCOMClient")
devtools::install_github("dkyleward/RDCOMClient")
library("devtools")
install_github('omegahat/RDCOMClient')
```

errors :
Warning message:
package ‘RDCOMClient’ is not available (for R version 3.6.0)
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.6:
cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'
Package which is only available in source form, and may need
These will not be installed
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = h) : 
Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10015 milliseconds

Comment: Did you try: `install.packages("RDCOMClient", repos = 'http://www.omegahat.net/R')` 
from [here](https://github.com/omegahat/RDCOMClient/issues/9)

Comment: Do you have RTools installed?

Comment: Hey David Klotz i am able to install using above code that you provided but on R 3.5.0 not on 3.6.0.However currently its fine for me.
Thanks a lot for your efforts and support.Really Appreciated!! :)